# Flex 4 remove selected item from spark DropDownList

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder, mxml

My stakeholder has a request to remove the currently selected item from the DropDownList control(s) in the application. For example a drop down with [item1, item2, item3, item4] if item2 is selected then the only items in the drop down will be [item1, item3, item4]

Any thoughts on if this is possible and if so how to implement it would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Using Flash Builder 4 with Flex 4.0 sdk

Answer (score 0):

As long as your dropdown list uses an ArrayCollection as a data provider, you can specify a filter function to remove the current selected entry:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            [Bindable] private var _yourAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3']);

            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                _yourAC.filterFunction = filter;
            }

            private function filter(item:Object):Boolean
            {
                return item != list.selectedItem;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:DropDownList id="list" dataProvider="{this._yourAC}" change="this._yourAC.refresh();" />
</s:Application>
```

I think this should filter out your selected item :)

Comment: The side effect of something like this is that the DropDownList will revert to the unselected state; since the selectedItem" is no longer in the dataProvider.  I'm unclear from the original post if this is an acceptable side effect or not.

Comment: OK, so that did remove the selected item from the list, but it also changed the view to show the next item in the list since it is actually at the index of the selected item. IE: Select item3 the header of the dropdown shows item4 as the currently selected item. So as the previous commenter pointed out, this is not acceptable functionality :(

Comment: Ah, right, didn't think about that.  You could easily extend the component to have this kind of functionality because by default, it doesn't.  I would search around because I'm fairly sure someone has done something similar in the past.

Answer (score 0):

No custom skinning needed. Just create a new ItemRenderer for your dropdownList and on the  the parent's change event, set `visible` and `includeInLayout` to false if `parent.selectedItem = data`. To avoid creating a brand new itemrenderer, you could potentially just extend spark's "defaultItemRenderer" class. If you use an MXML itemrenderer, simply set `visible="{data != (parent as DropDownList).selectedItem}"`, it should bind. If not, do it on an event as well.

Comment: OK, so that didn't work very well. It doesn't seem to bind, or ever work for that matter. One problem is that the direct parent of the item renderer isn't the drop down list. I tried adding an event listener, to set-up the change event on the parent, on the creationComplete event of the item renderer, but it hasn't been added to the parent at that point, I tried the add, added and addedToStage events, but they never fire.